datetime2 insertion in postgresql
good morning,
I'm working on a datalake that retrieves data from sqlserver, transforms it with dbt and then inserts it into postgresql.
The format of my source data has changed (the software editor has made changes in sqlserver) and I now have time datetime2 (0) or datetime2 (7) instead of datetime. Since this change, dbt has been giving me errors for each date column that was previously inserted as a timestamp, see first screen :  invalid input syntax for type date: "Mar 17 2021 08:21:19:0000000AM".
Especially since in my sqlserver table the writing is not the same as the insertion in postgresql. In sqlserver I have YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFFFFFF instead of the month on 3 letters in postgresql visible in the error. I have to cast in varchar to avoid insertion errors, but then I can't calculate durations (previously just end time - start time). I'm looking for a way to cleanly cast the displayed format of datetime(2) to timestamp
I tried
--TO_TIMESTAMP("date_debut", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') and i get   invalid value "Oct " for "YYYY"
and date_debut::timestamp
Any suggestions?

You clearly don't have your date_debut in the format you have specified. Presumably it is the ... format you mentioned previously


This Mar 17 2021 08:21:19:0000000AM should be Mar 17 2021 08:21:19.0000000AM then it would work. My suspicion is that dbt is the culprit. 2) The transform function should be select to_timestamp('Mar 17 2021 08:21:19:0000000AM', 'Mon DD YYYY HH:MI:SS:FF6'). The template needs to match the format  you are getting.


The format is not correct, you mention the ISO format but that will be the output from to_timestamp() anyway. You should mention how your input looks like. This one works for me:
SELECT to_timestamp('Mar 17 2021 08:21:19:0000000AM'
                   ,'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS:USAM');


What will be output is determined by what DateStyle is set to and can vary as shown here 8.5.2. Date/Time Output. So for instance if the DateStyle is set to German you would get something like 17.03.2021 08:21:19 PDT. In any case it does not really matter what the string representation is, as the data is not stored that way.

I agree it is supposed to be a representation but why can’t it be inserted as a timestamp ?My main problem is that in may the insertion was working without transformation just select date_debut was inserting a timestamp. Since then my service providers updated the full stack of datalake and now i get this problem and I don’t know what changed and what to correct in system

Thank you for your answer, i didn't knew the Mon DD YYYY syntax
Here is what i'm finally doing and it does work :
TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING(CAST("date_debut" AS VARCHAR(30)) FROM 1 FOR 20), 'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS')::timestamp AS date_debut



The template patterns are spelled out in the documentation: Data Formatting: Table 9.27. Template Patterns for Date/Time Formatting. 2) Your solution is unnecessarily complex. You don't need to do all that casting, just do to_timestamp('date string' , 'template string'), the output will be a timestamp so no need to cast it to one. Spend some time with the docs, your life will be easier for it.


Actually if i didn’t add the cast in the end i get a SS+00
My main problem is that in may the insertion was working without transformation just select date_debut was inserting a timestamp.
Since then my service providers updated the full stack of datalake and now i get this problem and I don’t know what changed and what to correct in system to avoid doing this This not-so-clean transformation
